# Long polling timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer, long-polling

I am new to long polling and don't quite grasp it's method. I already have a timer function in javascript that is controlled with buttons on one page [Code Below]. I want the same timer to run simultaneously on multiple pages (that can be on different computers and browsers). Except it will be controlled with buttons only from this page (timerMode.php). How could I do this with long pooling?
Note: I use phpMyAdmin SQL Database. The same svg will be used for every timer

timerMode.php:

```js
var timerMode = function() {
  var timergc;
  var runningsc = false;
  var runninggc = false;
  var endedsc = false;
  var edndedgc = false;
  var startTimer = function(seconds, container, oncomplete, type) {
    var startTime, timer, obj, ms = seconds * 1000;
    var paused = false;
    var display = document.getElementById(container);
    obj = {};
    obj.resume = function() {
      paused = false;
      startTime = new Date().getTime();
      timer = setInterval(obj.step, 100);
    };
    obj.pause = function() {
      if (!paused) {
        paused = true;
        ms = obj.step();
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    };
    obj.reset = function(res) {
      ms = res * 1000;
      m = Math.floor(ms / 60000), s = Math.floor(ms / 1000) % 60;
      switch (type) {
        case "game":
          if (m == 0) {
            var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
            display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
          } else {
            s = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;
            display.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
          }
          break;
        case "shot":
          if (s <= 4) {
            var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
            display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
          } else display.innerHTML = s;
          break;
      }
    };
    obj.modify = function(diff) {
      if (diff == 1) {
        if (ms < seconds * 1000) {
          ms += diff * 1000;
          m = Math.floor(ms / 60000), s = Math.floor(ms / 1000) % 60;
          if (type == "shot") {
            if (s <= 4) {
              var mili = String(ms % 1000).charAt(0);
              display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
            } else display.innerHTML = s;
          } else {
            if (m == 0) {
              var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
              display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
            } else {
              s = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;
              display.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (Math.floor(ms / 1000) % 60 > 0) {
          ms += diff * 1000;
          m = Math.floor(ms / 60000), s = Math.floor(ms / 1000) % 60;
          if (type == "shot") {
            if (s <= 4) {
              var mili = String(ms % 1000).charAt(0);
              display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
            } else display.innerHTML = s;
          } else {
            if (m == 0) {
              var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
              display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
            } else {
              s = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;
              display.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
    obj.step = function() {
      var now = Math.max(0, ms - (new Date().getTime() - startTime)),
        m = Math.floor(now / 60000),
        s = Math.floor(now / 1000) % 60;
      switch (type) {
        case "game":
          if (m == 0) {
            var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
            display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
          } else {
            s = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;
            display.innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
          }
          break;
        case "shot":
          if (s <= 4) {
            var mili = String(now % 1000).charAt(0);
            display.innerHTML = s + "." + mili;
          } else display.innerHTML = s;
          break;
      }
      if (now == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        if (type == "shot") {
          runningsc = false;
          runninggc = false;
          endedsc = true;
        }
        if (oncomplete) oncomplete();
      }
      return now;
    };
    obj.resume();
    return obj;
  };
  $(document).on("click", "#start", function() {
    timergc = startTimer(600, "game_clock", function() {}, "game");
    timersc = startTimer(24, "shot_clock", function() {}, "shot");
    runningsc = true;
    runninggc = true;
    $(".gcbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".gcbtn_main").attr("id", "pausegc");
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "pausesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#pausegc", function() {
    timergc.pause();
    timersc.pause();
    runningsc = false;
    runninggc = false;
    $(".gcbtn_main").text("Resume");
    $(".gcbtn_main").attr("id", "resumegc");
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Resume");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "resumesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#resumegc", function() {
    timergc.resume();
    runninggc = true;
    if (!runningsc) {
      timersc.resume();
      runningsc = true;
    }
    $(".gcbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".gcbtn_main").attr("id", "pausegc");
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "pausesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#resetgc", function() {
    timergc.pause();
    timergc.reset(600);
    timersc.pause();
    timersc.reset(24);
    $(".gcbtn_main").text("Start");
    $(".gcbtn_main").attr("id", "resumegc");
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "pausesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#upgc", function() {
    console.log(runninggc);
    timergc.pause();
    timergc.modify(1);
    if (runninggc) {
      timergc.resume();
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#downgc", function() {
    timergc.pause();
    timergc.modify(-1);
    if (runninggc) {
      timergc.resume();
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#pausesc", function() {
    timersc.pause();
    runningsc = false;
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Resume");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "resumesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#resumesc", function() {
    timersc.resume();
    runningsc = true;
    $(".scbtn_main").text("Pause");
    $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "pausesc");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#reset14", function() {
    timersc.pause();
    timersc.reset(14);
    if (runningsc) {
      timersc.resume();
    }
    if (endedsc) {
      $(".scbtn_main").text("Resume");
      $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "resumesc");
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#reset24", function() {
    timersc.pause();
    timersc.reset(24);
    if (runningsc) {
      timersc.resume();
    }
    if (endedsc) {
      $(".scbtn_main").text("Resume");
      $(".scbtn_main").attr("id", "resumesc");
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#upsc", function() {
    timersc.pause();
    timersc.modify(1);
    endedsc = false;
    if (runningsc) {
      timersc.resume();
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#downsc", function() {
    timersc.pause();
    timersc.modify(-1);
    endedsc = false;
    if (runningsc) {
      timersc.resume();
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#upqrt", function() {
    console.log("Works");
    var quarter = $("#quarter").text();
    console.log(quarter);
    if (quarter == 4) {
      $("#quarter").text("E");
    }
    if (quarter < 4) {
      console.log(quarter);
      quarter++;
      $("#quarter").text(quarter);
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#downqrt", function() {
    var quarter = $("#quarter").text();
    if (quarter == "E") {
      $("#quarter").text(4);
    }
    if (quarter > 1) {
      quarter--
      $("#quarter").text(quarter);
    }
  });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  timerMode();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" id="page-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 432.7 198" style="enable-background:new 0 0 432.7 198;background:white;" xml:space="preserve">
        <style type="text/css">
          .st0 {
            fill: #FFFFFF;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
          }
          .st1 {
            fill: none;
          }
          .st2 {
            font-family: 'Helvetica';
          }
          .st3 {
            font-size: 58px;
          }
          .st4 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
          }
          .st5 {
            font-size: 42px;
          }
          .st6 {
            font-size: 18px;
          }
          .st7 {
            font-size: 46px;
          }
          .st8 {
            font-size: 50.9768px;
          }
          .st9 {
            stroke: #000000;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
          }
          .st10 {
            font-size: 23px;
          }
          .st11 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000000;
          }
        </style>

        <path id="XMLID_12_" class="st0" d="M125.9,114.8H44.1c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2V73.4c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2h81.8c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v37.2C130.1,112.9,128.2,114.8,125.9,114.8z" />
        <rect id="XMLID_9_" x="39.9" y="69.2" class="st1" width="90.2" height="45.6" />
        <text id="XMLID_10_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 99.3335 111.792)" class="st2 st3">0</text>
        <path id="XMLID_16_" class="st0" d="M387.9,114.8h-81.8c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2V73.4c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2h81.8
      c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v37.2C392.1,112.9,390.2,114.8,387.9,114.8z" />

        <rect id="home_rect" x="7.1" y="6.8" class="st1" width="129.8" height="36.3"></rect>
        <text id="home_name" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 7.0877 38.7791)" class="st2 st5">HOME</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_20_" x="42" y="159.5" class="st1" width="60.9" height="16.5" />
        <text id="XMLID_19_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 42.0301 173.6536)" class="st2 st6">FOULS:</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_22_" x="112.5" y="160.5" class="st1" width="10.7" height="16" />
        <text id="XMLID_21_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 112.4562 174.6557)" class="st2 st6">0</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_33_" x="186.7" y="145.9" class="st1" width="59.4" height="36.6" />
        <text id="shot_clock" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 191.8234 179.9915)" class="st2 st7">24</text>
        <rect id="away_rect" x="295.1" y="6.8" class="st1" width="129.8" height="36.3" />
        <text id="away_name" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 295.0877 38.7791)" class="st2 st5">AWAY</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_5_" x="153.2" y="6.8" class="st1" width="125.6" height="36.3" />
        <text id="game_clock" transform="matrix(0.8828 0 0 1 165.1738 43.0225)" class="st2 st8">10:00</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_15_" x="301.9" y="69.2" class="st1" width="90.2" height="45.6" />
        <text id="XMLID_14_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 301.8873 111.792)" class="st2 st3">0</text>
        <g id="XMLID_11_">
          <text id="quarter" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 209.3371 99.3377)" class="st9 st2 st10">1</text>
        </g>
        <path id="XMLID_13_" class="st11" d="M221,103.6h-10.4c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2V83.2c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2H221
      c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v16.2C225.2,101.7,223.3,103.6,221,103.6z" />
        <path id="XMLID_18_" class="st11" d="M123,180.7h-10.4c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2v-16.2c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2H123
      c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v16.2C127.2,178.9,125.3,180.7,123,180.7z" />
        <path id="XMLID_31_" class="st11" d="M245.2,186.3h-57.3c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2v-36.7c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2h57.3
      c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v36.7C249.4,184.4,247.5,186.3,245.2,186.3z" />
        <rect id="XMLID_30_" x="300.7" y="158.7" class="st1" width="60.9" height="16.5" />
        <text id="XMLID_29_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 300.6767 172.9018)" class="st2 st6">FOULS:</text>
        <rect id="XMLID_28_" x="371.1" y="159.7" class="st1" width="10.7" height="16" />
        <text id="XMLID_26_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 371.1028 173.9038)" class="st2 st6">0</text>
        <path id="XMLID_23_" class="st11" d="M381.7,180h-10.4c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2v-16.2c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2h10.4
      c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v16.2C385.9,178.1,384,180,381.7,180z" />
        <circle id="XMLID_17_" cx="155" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />
        <circle id="XMLID_35_" cx="165" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />
        <circle id="XMLID_36_" cx="175" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />
        <circle id="XMLID_39_" cx="257" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />
        <circle id="XMLID_38_" cx="267" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />
        <circle id="XMLID_37_" cx="277" cy="91.3" r="2.5" />

      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Game Clock</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
                <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg gcbtn_main">Start</button>
                <button id="resetgc" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Reset</button>
                <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="margin-left:5px;">
                  <button id="upgc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button id="downgc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">:24</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
                <button id="pausesc" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg scbtn_main">Pause</button>
                <div class="btn-group" style="margin-left:5px;">
                  <button id="reset14" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">:14</button>
                  <button id="reset24" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">:24</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="margin-left:5px;">
                  <button id="upsc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button id="downsc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Quarter</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="margin-left:5px;">
                  <button id="upqrt" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button id="downqrt" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try and isolate the problem?

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to run the timer simultaneously on multiple pages. I know I should use long polling, but I don't know how

Comment: Not sure if long polling is possible with javascript and php. An alternative is to use ajax in each client to query a "master" php page on the server, often. This "master" is controlled with a "master client" page with all the button you want and also ajax. The only real issue is the precision : the clock between everyone could lag from 10 to 100ms